# Difference between structure instance and name

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, typedef

What is the difference between

```
typedef struct complex {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

and

```
typedef struct complex { 
    int x;
    int y;
} comp;
```

What does the additional `comp` in the second case do?
I have tried defining a new variable of type `complex` in the first case and using `comp` in the second case, both produced the same result... Please help!

Answer (score 4):

The first `typedef` is useless, the compile may give you a warning for it.

After the second `typedef`, whenever you use `struct complex` as a type, you can use `comp` instead. You can modify the second code into this equivalent form:

```
struct complex { 
    int x;
    int y;
};
typedef struct complex comp;
```

You can see that `struct complex` defines a type, while `typedef` gives it an alternative name.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of typedef is to assign a simple name to a type declaration made of one or more type components.

In the first declaration, you do not assign any name to your structure named complex.  Therefore the compiler will be generating a warning:

```
i.e. warning: declaration does not declare anything
```

Usually, when using typedef with structures [ or unions ], it is preferable (less verbose) to use unnamed structures, as in:

```
typedef struct {int x; int y;} complex;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct complex {
    int x;
    int y;
} comp;
```

This is the shorthand of creating variable of type complex.
comp is present before ; so it is treated as variable of type complex.look ar following code also

```
struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} comp;
```

You can also do this with old compilers that creates a variable of its struct type.

Comment: Please note that 'variable name' has different meaning under typedef, and this is not the case that you described.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short :

```
struct complex {
    int x;
    int y;
};
// forces you to use :
struct complex c;
```

But :

```
typedef struct complex {
    int x;
    int y;
} comp;
// allows you to use :
comp c;
```

Typedefs are just a matter of readabilty